# How do you stop a MongoDB search from being applied recursively to the key-value tree?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

Imagine I have this object (written with Ruby literals) stored in a MongoDB:

```
{"tags" => ["foo", "bar"], 
 "jobs" => [{"title" => "Chief Donkey Wrangler", "tags" => ["donkeys"]}] }
```

Now, I want to search for objects based on the tags on the first level of data, not the second. I can write a query like this (using the Ruby MongoDB library):

```
things.find("tags" => {"$exists" => "foo"})
```

This will obviously match the first example, but it will also match an example like this:

```
{"tags" => ["baz", "bar"],
 "jobs" => [{"title" => "Trainee Donkey Wrangler", "tags" => ["donkeys", "foo"]}] }
```

How do I ensure that I am searching only the top-level of keys? I'm interested in knowing the answer in both JavaScript, Ruby and in a language-agnostic way, as I'd like to use MongoDB as a cross-language store.

Obviously, I could pass a map-reduce function to the datastore to pick out the stuff I'm trying to get, but I'm interested to see if it is supported at a higher level (and to reduce the amount of time I spend writing JavaScript map-reduce functions!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the query you specify won't match your second example. To match the second example, you'd do:

```
things.find({"jobs.tags" => "foo"})
```

There's no recursive application of the query selector.

Comment: Oh, okay, that's strange. If I use the $exists filter, it does do a recursive match, but if I do it using the simpler match, it doesn't. Strange. Well, cheers for the answer.

Comment: Right, the problem is that $exists works like a boolean -- either a truthy value or false. So your original query is matching any document with a "tags" key.  The "foo" isn't being processed.

Comment: It seems like there's a bug in the Ruby library that is interpreting any string passed as an argument as equivalent to passing true.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using $exists properly. $exists does not allow you to search for a match of a field, it just checks for the existence of such a field. I'm guessing that the Ruby MongoDB library is treating your request for 'foo' as equivalent to true, b/c $exists only accepts true/false as an argument

As @kb points out, you want to use the [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) to reach into the objects.